# How to Change Woocommerce "Sort By" Text?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

how to change, in last version Woocommerce, this text - [image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Why not search for the text in the code to see where it comes from?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but nothing could ... apparently I'm not very well versed in the code..(

Comment: Describing what you tried helps us avoid time telling you to do things you've already done. And/or it helps us quickly point out errors in the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 9):

I hope better way to solve your problem. Just copy and paste your theme of functions.php. Okay

```
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wc_customize_product_sorting');

function wc_customize_product_sorting($sorting_options){
    $sorting_options = array(
        'menu_order' => __( 'Sorting', 'woocommerce' ),
        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),
        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $sorting_options;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can change the options of the orderby via the [`woocommerce_catalog_orderby`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/36dad31b4537c6660849fe695800312f1852b03d/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L773) filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'so_37445423_orderby_options', 20 );

function so_37445423_orderby_options( $options ){
    $options['menu_order'] = __('Sort the normal way', 'your-child-theme');
    return $options;
}
```

I've added the 20 priority, because I'm guessing that your theme is already filtering this and/or hard-coding them into the `orderby.php` template. I'm guessing this because the default WooCommerce has "Default sorting" instead of "Sort by Default". "Sort by name" is also not a part of core.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your themes function.php .  Change the translation according to your requirement.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_sort_change', 20, 3 );
function theme_sort_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {

        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'Sort by newness' :

                $translated_text = __( 'Sort by Newest', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;
        }

    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Reference : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-woocommerce-sort-by-text

Answer (score -1):

For the guys, who is looking for it's solution in 2017-2018(Version 4.9.1)...

wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > includes > wc-template-functions.php

Search for: "function woocommerce_catalog_ordering()". Here it's line 831.

```
        'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),
        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),
        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' ),
```

All the text can be change in this function.

Comment: It is never a good practice to overwrite the _core files_, as with an update they get updated too.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to change them? If you want to change the language, then use a language pack (that might work for changing the texts in English also)

Comment: Because in other languages woocommerce often not fully translated, and in my case part descriptions, menus, answers are not translated, so I translate myself!

Comment: So you have already downloaded a translation pack? So why not just translate those untranslated parts in the .po file and make new .mo file out of it.

Comment: Since the options are saying something other than the default, I would guess your theme has modified the values, which might not have complete language packs. WooCommerce core is translated into a lot of languages.

Answer (score -3):

I hope better way to solve your problem. Just copy and paste your theme of functions.php. Okay

```
function wc_customize_product_sorting($sorting_options){
    $sorting_options = array(
        'menu_order' => __( 'Sorting', 'woocommerce' ),
        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),
        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $sorting_options;
}
```

add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wc_customize_product_sorting');

Comment: Please delete this answer as a duplicate.